# Update database with multiple SQL Statments

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

I am using mysql connector.Python 1.0.9 downloaded from MySQL site.

I have a sample [table here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a7cb5/1)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table; 
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Shot VARCHAR(4),
sec varchar(5),
lay VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lay_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
blk VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
blk_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pri VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
pri_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ani VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ani_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'SH01','3','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','Over'),
(2,'SH02','2.5','1863','yes','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','no','Over'),
(3,'SH03','0.5','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','1863','yes','1863','yes','WIP'),
(4,'SH04','1.25','1863','no','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','yes','RTK'),
(5,'SH05','1','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','WIP'),
(6,'SH06','6','P4557','yes','P4645','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','WIP');
```

i am able to execute a single SQL statment as below.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

SQL = '''
        update my_table 
        set 
        LAY = 'P6682'
        , BLK = 'P6682'
        , ANI = 'P6682'
        where
        Shot = 'SH01';
      '''

cursor.execute(SQL)
```

and everything is fine and database gets updated correctly.

now when i am trying to update the database with multiple statements as below

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

SQL = '''
    update my_table 
    set 
    LAY = 'P6682'
    , BLK = 'P6682'
    , ANI = 'P6682'
    where
    Shot = 'SH01';

    update my_table 
    set 
    LAY = '1863'
    , BLK = '1863'
    , ANI = '1863'
    where
    Shot = 'SH02'
'''

cursor.execute(SQL)
cnx.commit()
cur.close()
cnx.close()
cnx.disconnect()
```

I get below trackback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_Module.py", line 24, in 
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 396, in execute
    "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements")
InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements
```

I update my command as below

```
cursor.execute(SQL,multi = True)

cnx.commit()
cur.close()
cnx.close()
cnx.disconnect()
```

Now i dont get any error/Traceback. But the database is not getting updated.

Can any one tell me where am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At-last after a long research on docs and help. I could able to solve the issue.

Using a `for` loop at `cursor.execute` with `multi=True` worked. I don't know why we need to loop through.

```
for result in cursor.execute(SQL, multi=True):
    pass
```

Without loop just `cursor.execute(SQL, multi=True)` did not do any changes in the database.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

SQL = '''
    update my_table 
    set 
    LAY = 'P6682'
    , BLK = 'P6682'
    , ANI = 'P6682'
    where
    Shot = 'SH01';

    update my_table 
    set 
    LAY = '1863'
    , BLK = '1863'
    , ANI = '1863'
    where
    Shot = 'SH02'
'''

for result in cursor.execute(SQL, multi=True):
    pass

cnx.commit()
cur.close()
cnx.close()
cnx.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working.

Comment: It'd be great if a mysql.connector guru could _explain_ why the for loop is necessary.

Comment: good to know: For python 3.7+, make sure you have MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.13 or later ( https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87818 )

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the MySQL docs

> If multi is set to True, execute() is able to execute multiple statements specified in the operation string. It returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement. However, using parameters does not work well in this case, and it is usually a good idea to execute each statement on its own.

so setting multi=True returns an iterator and if you just want to loop through each statement, the other solution offered works well:

```
for result in cursor.execute(SQL, multi=True):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have somekind of commit

```
cnx.commit()
```

[MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myconnpy_tutorial_CursorBuffered_GiveRaise.html)

Comment: ,i have `cnx.commit()` i did not write in my question. i have updated my question with `cnx.commit()`

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use executemany, as follows:

```py
sql=('insert into articulos (descripcion, precio) values(%s,%s)')  
data=[('naranjas',22), ("pomelos", 29), ("frutillas", 130)]

cursor.executemany(sql,data)
```