# Mysql updates with IN and separate statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Which is faster in MySql?
I will be executing following bunch of statements via my python scirpt at one go using [multi=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288594/update-database-with-multiple-sql-statments)

```
update table keyword set qs=4 where adid = 'adid-1'
update table keyword set qs=4 where adid = 'adid-2'
update table keyword set qs=4 where adid = 'adid-3'
update table keyword set qs=4 where adid = 'adid-4'
```

OR

```
update table keyword set qs=4 where adid in ('adid-1', 'adid-2', 'adid-3','adid-4')
```

Comment: Why you dont try it and check the explain plan? My guess is both will have similar performace if you have an index for `adid ` other wise second one will be faster because only one table scan.

Comment: are those seperate calls all in mySQL procedure or are you going from one app to the database across a network?  if across network then likely the 1 update would be faster.  So as you can see "Faster" may be subjective and is context dependent.

Comment: @xQbert How going around a network option 1 will be faster? I think would need 4 round trip, when second one only need one.

Comment: So I will be executing bunch of the statements at one go from my python script, using multi=true

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  the 1 update will be faster.  4 calls would be slower.  "the 1 update would be faster"  4 updates slower.  of course you could muti thread the app and parallel process the 4 calls passed at the same time and let the database work out the order of operation.  Then that would be faster but take more processor at one time.

Comment: As a general rule, try to minimize the number of queries you perform. If a single query can do the same work as 4 separate queries, it's usually preferable.

Comment: @Barmar Unless your queries are slow process, in that case using parallelism and send multiple query will improve performance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I said "in general", meaning there may be exceptions. To get parallelism you'll need to use multiple threads and database connections, and ensure that the queries don't block each other.